# unknown issue in using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am new to Android and I want to make an application based on REST API.

So I search and found the Retrofit 2.

I used a sample of retrofit that I found in Github to learn how it works.

This files are my Java classes :

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textv = findViewById(R.id.textv);
        GitHubClient gitHubClient;
        gitHubClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(GitHubClient.class);

        final Call<GitHubUser> call = gitHubClient.getFeed("google");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GitHubUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GitHubUser> call, Response<GitHubUser> response) {
                GitHubUser gitModel = response.body();
                if (gitModel != null) {
                    textv.setText(getString(R.string.main_response_text,
                            gitModel.getName(),
                            gitModel.getBlog()));
                } else {
                    textv.setText("user doesn't exist");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GitHubUser> call, Throwable t) {
                textv.setText(t.getMessage());
            }

        });

    }

}
```

`GithubClient.java`

```
public interface GitHubClient {
    @GET("users/{user}")
    Call<GitHubUser> getFeed(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

`ServiceGenerator.java`

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    private static Interceptor logging = interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

`GithubUser.java`

```
public class GitHubUser {

    private String name;
    private String blog;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBlog() {
        return blog;
    }

}
```

JSON code from Github

```
{
  ...
  "name": "Google",
  "blog": "https://opensource.google.com/",
  ...
}
```

I want to get the name and blog URL

And when I run the program the output is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb8952b10: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version(external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x83bc3770:0x00000000)
```

What's the problem and how can I fix?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?. I mean post the log cat error or something..!!

Comment: as i said i just get unknown error from  textv.setText("unknown error");

Comment: What is the response you are expecting?. Because if the response and POJO "GitHubUser" doesnt match, it goes to onFailure()

Comment: can you explain more? this Github user:

public class GitHubUser {

    private String name;
    private String blog;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBlog() {
        return blog;
    }

}

Comment: I mean the response should match you POJO structure. Please post the response you are expecting along with GithubUser POJO so that we understand the issue better..!

Comment: You are using Gson right?

Comment: yes ,     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

Comment: Please try the answer and let me know..!

Comment: Your code looks correct, do clean build and test.

Comment: What is in the `Throwable t` parameter when `onFailure` is called?

Answer (score 0):

The first step here would be to understand the error.

Try printing the error from your onFailure method like this:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<GitHubUser> call, Throwable t) {
    textv.setText("unknown error"); // can also do textv.setText(t.getMessage()) to display error reason
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should get in your logcat some more useful information about what went wrong, it will be easier to figure out how to solve it after that
Also have you added internet access permission in your manifest?

Comment: Not quite sure here, from what I read there are some issues with okhttp on some android versions, do you have the possibility to test it with different android versions?

Answer (score 0):

SSL Exception comes when SSL Certificate issue . You need to add ssl certificate to server side.

Comment: server side is github!

Comment: some times old Android version not permssion to support that type of certificate .What is name of Android version which you are used ?

Comment: i used nox app player 6 for test the app

Comment: name of android version @daniel

Comment: You can also check another example of retrofit  and another api .https://github.com/kamydeep00178/androidMvvm

Comment: android 4.4 , and i will check this link, i want something simple for learning actually

Comment: ok only change the rest api which you are used and then i think problem is soloved . and other you can test your code to Android Heigher Version

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

in your manifest  tag

also put the following file in res >> xml >>

*network_security_config.xml*

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">static.food2fork.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```